# Display form on click, smooth transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tz52u/9/

I wondered how do I make the 'on click' a smooth transition, so it gradually displays on the page, rather than being instantaneous?

Any help much appreciated, the code of the fiddle is below.

[html]

```
<div class="row no-show">
                        <p class="left-a">
                            <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
                            <input type="text" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer" value="" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="middle-a">
                            <label for="product_code">Product Code</label>
                            <input type="text" name="product_code" id="product_code" value="" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="middle-b">
                            <label for="condition">Condition</label>
                            <select name="condition">
                                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="newsealed">New & Sealed</option>
                                <option value="tattybox">Tatty Box</option>
                                <option value="openbox">Opened Box</option>
                                <option value="openbag">Opened Bag</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                        <p class="right-a">
                            <label for="quantity">Qty</label>
                            <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <button id="show" class="button purple">Add More Products</button>
```

[jquery]

```
  $("#show").click(function(){
      console.log("Button clicked!");
    $(".no-show").show();
  });
```

[css]

```
.no-show{display:none;}
```

Comment: $(".no-show").slideToggle(); - or fadeIn(), a matter of taste, i guess..

Comment: Use jQuery function `fadeIn` to work around this, look at http://jsfiddle.net/tz52u/19/

Comment: I think that is better if you use toggle instead of just show...
http://jsfiddle.net/tz52u/20/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
$("#show").click(function(){
  console.log("Button clicked!");
  $(".no-show").fadeIn(1500);
  $("#show").hide();
  $("#show").fadeIn(1500);
});
```

I am hiding the Button so it reemerges with the Text again for the "smotthness"

Comment: Or you can do the fadeOut and after the fadeIn

Comment: Thanks this is great, is it possible to click the button and then for the item close in the same way?

Comment: You can use the `.toggle()` function instead of `.fadeIn()` in the above example. Documentation for the `.toggle()` function, including examples, can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as passing a duration to the .show() method:

```
$(".no-show").show(5000);
```

See jQuery docs about the show method: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion after playing around with your fiddle for 5 minutes is:

```
 $("#show").click(function(){
   console.log("Button clicked!");
   $(".no-show").slideToggle(2000);
   $("#show").delay(2000).fadeOut(150).fadeIn(150);
 });
```

jQuery is like magic!